# Standard deviation and mean changes between two conditions: how to test both changes within one statistical model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, equivalence

I have two experimental conditions called *rest* and *task*. The conditions include 13 subjects, respectively.

I computed the *mean* and *standard deviation (SD)* for each subject’s data. Consequently, I have two lists of data:

- 13 mean values (for rest and task, respectively)
- 13 SD values (for rest and task, respectively)

There are two hypotheses that I would like to test:

- **Hypothesis one:** The rest vs. task mean difference is not statistically significant (i.e., it remains more or less the same from rest to task).
- **Hypothesis two:** The rest vs. task SD difference is statistically significant.

I use an equivalence test to test hypothesis one, and I use a paired t-test to test hypothesis two.

**Question:**
Is there an option to statistically test both hypotheses within one model (instead of running two separate test as explained above)? Someone suggested me a 2x2 design. However, I see no way to include my two hypotheses into a 2x2 design because the 2x2 design requires qualitative levels of data (such as smokers vs. non-smokers), and I do not have such qualitative levels in my data.

I have the feeling that a separate equivalence and t-test is the optimal solution to test my questions/hypotheses, but I would like to know if there is a chance to combine both hypothesis into one statistical model.